# Unchecked runtime.lastError: No tab with <id>, Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I don't understand why i recieve this error

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xUnl.png)

This code works

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(handleUrls);

function handleUrls(tabId, { changeInfo }, tab) {

    const isOauthTokenPage = tab.url?.match(CONFIG.OAUTH_TOKEN_PAGE_PATTERN);

    if (isOauthTokenPage) {
        chrome.tabs.remove(tabId);
    }
}
```

But why i get this error?

I tried `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener` before and after `chrome.tabs.remove(tabId)`, tried `chrome.tabs.query` to get "actual" `tabId`

Comment: `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` 
This will actually trigger multiple times when a page URL is changed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So it's trigger more than once

To avoid it

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    // check url state
    if (!changeInfo.url) return;
    
    // your code...
    if ((tab.url).match(CONFIG.OAUTH_TOKEN_PAGE_PATTERN)) {
        // won't invoke onUpdated several times
        chrome.tabs.remove(tabId);
    }
});
```

Comment: No, the problem was a typo in your initial code: `{ changeInfo }` should be `changeInfo`.

Comment: OMG, its you, thanks. See my answer, i use `changeInfo`

Comment: `onUpdated` can invoke several times, i checked it with `chrome.notifications.create` with `message: tab.url` and it shows more than one notidication

Comment: Multiple invocation indeed can cause problems but notifications are not a part of your question's [MCVE](/help/mcve). BTW in some cases it may be easier to simply suppress the error by adding a callback: chrome.tabs.remove(tabId, ()=>chrome.runtime.lastError)

Comment: `chrome.tabs.remove(tabId, ()=>chrome.runtime.lastError)` this code works fine. But now i recieve 4 errors -> `Uncaught (in promise) Error: No tab with id: 170952365`
is it possible to ignore errors if they don't block program?

Comment: It means there's more places where you use chrome.tabs or a similar tabId-based API. You can suppress the error using the same trick, but only if you don't need th result of the API call, otherwise it should be used differently.